# jQuery - wait until function execution is complete

Tags: jquery

Given the following code:

```
$(classeDoFlipContainer).css('z-index', '1');
$(classeOpostaDoFlipContainer).css('z-index', '0');

flipBox.flippy({
    color_target: "white",
    duration: "900",
    verso: versoDaImagem,
    direction: "BOTTOM",
    onFinish: setEventHandlers,
    onReverseFinish: setEventHandlers
});

alert('?');
$(classeDoFlipContainer).css('z-index', '0');
$(classeOpostaDoFlipContainer).css('z-index', '1');
```

I added the `alert('?');` just to verify that the code after `flippy()` is being executed. But I need it only when `flippy()` is completely done. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `onFinish` callback provided by flippy:

```
flipBox.flippy({
  color_target: "white",
  duration: "900",
  verso: versoDaImagem,
  direction: "BOTTOM",
  onFinish: function(){
    setEventHandlers();
    alert('?');
    $(classeDoFlipContainer).css('z-index', '0');
    $(classeOpostaDoFlipContainer).css('z-index', '1');
  },
  onReverseFinish: setEventHandlers
});
```

EDIT: you may also want to add the `onReverseFinish` callback

Comment: Actually I use it to do other things, but I can write another function to call `setEventHandlers` and the last two lines, only for `onFinish`.

Comment: You can call `setEventHandlers` in the `onFinish` function too. Look at the updated answer...

Comment: It is OK for me! Thank you. As you were the first to answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `onFinish` callback:

```
flipBox.flippy({
    color_target: "white",
    duration: "900",
    verso: versoDaImagem,
    direction: "BOTTOM",
    onFinish: function(){
        alert('?');
    },
    onReverseFinish: setEventHandlers
});
```

Comment: Thank you too! It's just like @ipeiro said.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

```
onFinish:function()
{
    alert("yey!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the attention. All other answers lead to the same way.